# Selenium dynamic scraping code only working when ran multiple times in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have been trying to dynamically scrape a news website using python and return back the text version of the live headlines. For now, I have decided to just return the div. I had success with sometimes making it work. If I run the code at least three times in quick succession, it returns back what I am looking for. However, when ran once, it returns back a "Loading articles..." text instead of the headlines. I have tried buffering the code (thought that maybe it had to do with connection or the article loading on the software run browser but that wasn't the case). Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://newsfilter.io/latest/merger-and-acquisitions'
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\sam\\Documents\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

sauce= browser.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
browser.quit()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all('div'):
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents are loading dynamically, I would loop the website continuously to scrape the data like this,

```
# SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI

import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://newsfilter.io/latest/merger-and-acquisitions'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

unique_div = []

while True:
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.find_all('div'):
        if i.text not in unique_div:
            unique_div.append(i.text)
            print(i.text)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

`unique_div` will contain unique elements.

**Note:** The above program does not know when to stop, So you can write something like to check the length of unique elements before scraping and the length of unique elements after scraping. If the length remains same then no new elements are found in the website. Something like this,

```
unique_div = []

while True:
    previous_length = len(unique_div)
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.find_all('div'):
        if i.text not in unique_div:
            unique_div.append(i.text)
            #print(i.text)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    after_scraped = len(unique_div)
    if previous_length == after_scraped:
        print("Scraped Everything")
        break
```

I would go for WebdriverWait insteand of time.sleep(secs) anyways. [Waits in Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).